# Drawing circle in Java

Tags: java

hey I have created Class Circle

```
public class Circle {
    private double sX;
    private double sY;
    private int radius;

    public Circle(int sX, int sY, int radius) {
        this.sX = sX;
        this.sY = sY;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    public void drawCircle(G_Graphics graphics, G_Color color){
        for (int y = -radius; y <= radius; y++) {
            for (int x = -radius; x <= radius; x++) {
                if((Math.pow(y,2)+Math.pow(x,2))==(Math.pow(radius,2))){
                    graphics.putPixel(x+((int)sX),y+((int)sY),color);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to print it using my method `graphics.putPixel(x+((int)sX),y+((int)sY),color);` 
but it only prints couple dots around radius of circle

[image]

so my question is how could I make it draw full circle?

EDIT:here is methot that prints on canvas, G_Graphics contains more methods but I had to delete them to be able to post here

```
package com;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
public class G_Graphics {

private BufferedImage bitmap;
private Graphics2D g;


public G_Graphics(BufferedImage b) {
    bitmap = b;
    g = bitmap.createGraphics();
}

public void putPixel(int x, int y, G_Color color) {
    Color color_help = new Color(color.r, color.g, color.b);

    bitmap.setRGB(x, y, color_help.getRGB());
}
```

}

Comment: To draw a circle, use `graphics.drawOval(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius)`

Comment: well my graphic is instance of object that is cutom aswell so I cannot use graphic.drawOval();

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Why are you not showing the method that actually places the pixels?

Comment: well I am using framework that we have in school and I dont want to make everything again just beacuse I cant find way to draw circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sweep from 0 to 360 degrees.  Convert your degrees to radians, and pass that to Cos() and Sin().  Multiply those values by your radius and add them to the center point.

Something like:

```
public void drawCircle(G_Graphics graphics, G_Color color){
    double degreesToRadians = Math.PI / 180.0;
    for(int degrees=0; degrees<=360; degrees++)
    {
        double radians = degreesToRadians * degrees;
        int X = (int)(sX + Math.cos(radians) * radius);
        int Y = (int)(sY + Math.sin(radians) * radius);           
        graphics.putPixel(X, Y, color);
    }
}
```

This will work for smaller circles.  For very large circles, you'd have to sweep from 0 to 360 using increments smaller than 1 (one).

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `Math.pow(i, 2)` to calculate the square of an integer. `pow()` uses `double` math, so the method is very slow, compared to just calculating `i * i`.

So, you condition should be written as:

```
if (x * x + y * y == radius * radius) {
```

Next, as to why that doesn't, it's because the pixels in the bitmap grid doesn't map exactly to the radius distance.

To illustrate, let us look at the upper-right quadrant of a circle with `radius = 5`. The right side of the equation is `radius * radius`, which means 25.

Since your code calculates `x * x + y * y` for every pixel, let's do that:

```
for (int y = 5; y >= 0; y--) {
    for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++)
        System.out.printf("%2d ", x * x + y * y);
    System.out.println();
}
```

```
25 26 29 34 41 50 
16 17 20 25 32 41 
 9 10 13 18 25 34 
 4  5  8 13 20 29 
 1  2  5 10 17 26 
 0  1  4  9 16 25
```

Let's plot the values exactly equal to `25`:

```
X . . . . .
. . . X . .
. . . . X .
. . . . . .
. . . . . .
. . . . . X
```

This is why your circle only has a few pixels, not a solid line.

Now think about how few of the pixels are actually on the border of the circle. Calculating for every pixel on the square bounding the circle is bad for performance. Re-think what you're doing, do some research, and use a better algorithm to raw a circle.